# Pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to C++ and I found this code in a tutorial. I am perplexed to find double stars instead of a single star used for defining a pointer. Is this a substitute for two dimensional array? If yes how?

For example:

```
int* A = new int[5];
```

makes an array strip , how does it happen in `int **A`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

 int **A;
    A = new int*[10] ;

    for (int j=0; j<20; j++) 
       A[j] = new int[20] ;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
       for (int j=0; j<20; j++) 
        A[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1);


    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       for (int j=0; j<20; j++) 
        cout << A[i][j] << " ";
       cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Maybe you will find this interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That is two-dimensional array: more precisely, pointer to pointer!

And you've to deallocate it once you're done with it. This is how you've to delete it:

```
for (int j=0; j<20; j++) 
   delete[] A[j];
delete[] A;
```

It's good that you're experimenting with it. It would be also good if you also get familiar with `std::vector` and experiment with it as well.

---

Example of `std::vector`

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int> > A(10, vector<int>(20));

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
   for (int j=0; j<20; j++) 
    A[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1);

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<20; j++) 
    cout << A[i][j] << " ";
   cout << endl;
}
```

That is, if you use `std::vector`, then you don't have to worry about allocation and deallocation of memory!

Demo at ideone: http://ideone.com/LEOBe

Comment: hi nawaz, what exactly is std::vector? and how can i utilize it? can u give me a sample code? thanks for replying buddy!

Comment: and by the way if I want to delete it why should j go from 0 to 20?

Comment: @Frustrated Coder - I find that mastering the standard libraries to a language is hands down the easiest way to learn a language. You're on the right track!

Comment: Just a caution - C++ *has* something called multi-dimensional arrays, and this isn't one of them. A vector of vectors, and an array of pointers to arrays, can both *represent* a two-dimensional array, and both allow the `[][]` syntax, but that isn't C++'s name for them.

Answer (score 3):

`int **A;` means it is a pointer to a pointer. This is often used to represent a two-dimensional array. In you program -

```
int *A; A = new int[10] ;

for (int j=0; j<20; j++) 
   A[j] = new int[20] ; // A[j] means dereferencing to the location itself. So, it should hold `int`
                        // as stated but not `int*` that is returned by new operator.
```

`A` is pointer that points **10** memory locations that can hold `int`. And when you say, `A[j]` you are actually dereferencing to location. So, it holds an `int` not an `int*`. Also, there is a overflow since the number of locations `A` points to **10** but not **20** memory locations.

**Edit 1:** OP has edited the program. It's not the same as was earlier.

Now, the program is fine, with exception of returning resources back to free store.

```
int **A;
A = new int*[10] ;
```

`A` is a pointer to pointer. So, a should hold the address of a pointer or an array that can hold address of pointers. So,

```
A = new int*[10] ;
```

`A` holds the beginning address of an array of pointers whose size is `10`. Now this is still wrong.

```
for (int j=0; j<20; j++) 
   A[j] = new int[20] ; // Because `A[j]` is invalid from 10-19. There is no such index where A[j] can dereference to. So, j should run from 0 to 10 instead.
```

With that correctected -

```
A[j] = new int[20] ;
```

Now each pointer is pointing to 20 int locations. So, there are 10*20 elements in the array.

This diagram of a **2*3** dimensional array should give you an idea. Also, you should consider @Nawaz answer of deallocating the array, since resources are managed by programmer.

[image: 2*3 Array Lay Out]

Comment: @Frustrated Coder - Drawing a memory layout for 10*20 is a bit tough task ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's a pointer to a pointer. In this case, it's a 2D array.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to know is the difference between a pointer and an array in C and C++. An array `type array[size]`is size consecutive cells of sizeof(type) data. A pointer is a variable that contains an address. The confusion comes from the fact that a pointer is used to store the address of the first cell of a dynamically allocated array (malloc in C, new [] in C++).

So, what is the difference between `int array[10]` and  `int* pi` ? array is a memory area of the size of 10 ints and pi is a variable which contains the address of an int.

To declare a two dimensions array you can type : `int array2d[10][10]` or you can declare a "pointer to pointer" such as `int** ppi`. Don't forget that id you use the second one, you will have to allocate both the first (an array of pointer) and the second (your actual array of ints) dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The two starts mean that it is a pointer to a pointer. This line:

```
  A = new int*[10];
```

Allocates space for 10 `int*` values.  Later, each of those `int*` values are initialized with:

```
   for (int j=0; j<20; j++) 
       A[j] = new int[20];
```

The result is a 'jagged array', or an array of arrays. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To create a 2D array, you can either create an array of arrays (this results in a jagged array), or you can create a 1D array and reference it in such a way that it's like a 2D array (this second method is kind of awkward).

```
// array of arrays
int **A = new int*[5]; // an array of potentially 5 int arrays
for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    A[i] = new int[5];
}

// access the array using two brackets
A[0][0] = 1; // element in the zeroth row and zeroth col = 1
A[1][0] = 2; // element in the first row and zeroth col = 2
// you must delete the inside arrays first before deleting the array of arrays
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    delete[] A[i];
}
delete[] A;
```

Comment: why is it required to do delete[] A[i] before delete[] A...what exactly is deleted when I do delete[] A[i].
Suppose i did delete[] A[1];?

Comment: @Frustrated Coder - The sample diagram I posted should answer the question. If you do `delete[] A[1];` only first row is deallocated and rest stay there.